# Django get relation name in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i am trying to create a crud where you can add stores, and select if the store is active or no, so my model looks like this:

```
class Store(models.Model):
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and my form:

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

Status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Status.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = "__all__"
```

what im trying to do is in the field status get the names of that relation,
example Active or Inactive but i am getting a select with Status object (1) and Status object (1)

[image: example]

Comment: What is the name of the field in the `Status` model that you want in the drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of the `Status` model. Add the field you want in the `__str__` method.

Like so:

```py
class Status(models.Model):
    [... Your fields...]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.<your_field>
```

By replacing `<your_field>` with the name of the field you want to be shown in your dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.only()` in your queryset instead of `.all()`.

`queryset=Status.objects.only('name_of_the_field_from_STATUS_Model'))`

Check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only)